# String substitution into a subprocess call

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

How would I perform this Unix command in Python correctly, substituting the given values `index, username, password` into the command?

#### abc.py

```
import subprocess,datetime
cmd = '\./splunk search "| dbinspect index=%s |timeformat= "%s" rename state as category | stats min(earliestTime) as earliestTime max(latestTime) as latestTime sum(sizeOnDiskMB) as MB by category " -auth %s:%s | grep -v "category" | grep -v "-"' %(index, username, password)

subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)
```

When I try to execute the command, I get the error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: You just have to escape it: `timeformat= "%%s"`

Comment: its shoeing error like unknown command 'timeformat'

Answer (score 0):

You have four "%s" format descriptors in the string and only three elements in the `(index, username, password)` tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get is pretty explanatory: you have four `%s` is your string, but only three values in the tuple you provide. May you forgot the `timeformat` value?

If you need to reuse the same parameter, you can use another form of string formatting, using `'some text and {0}'.format(my_string)`:

```
cmd = '\./splunk search "| dbinspect index={0} |timeformat= "{1}" rename state as category | stats min(earliestTime) as earliestTime max(latestTime) as latestTime sum(sizeOnDiskMB) as MB by category " -auth {2}:{3} | grep -v "category" | grep -v "-"'.format(index, timeformat, username, password)
```

Comment: here time format is to convert date and time into required format. Its not a variable which need to pass value….how to convert date time into a required fomat in this situtation

Comment: Ah ok, I got it! I think bernie's comment to your question is giving you the solution: the `%s` given as `timeformat` value has to be escaped.

Comment: Well, `print '%s %s %s' % ('aa', 'bb')` returns the error you have, when `print '%s %%s %s' % ('aa', 'bb')` does not. This also works for your example. Is this not the case for you?